# Hyperlink to SharePoint Library Folder

Tags: 2013, list, hyperlink

I would like to add a hyperlink to a SharePoint list, that directs the user to a folder within a library (the folder contains many scanned certificates).

The problem is the hyperlink is way too long (more than the 255 characters allowed):

```
https://preamble_goes_here/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fteams%2FRSD%2F_catalogs%2Fmasterpage%2FSS%20Test%20Certificates&View=%7B1392CB2E-942F-44EF-A04C-2F751D9F44B7%7D
```

Is there a way to shorten it so I can add the hyperlink to the list?

I can use the hyperlink to the library (where the user would than select the 
 corresponding folder), but I would like to directly link to the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add a folder path similar to how Windows does it, via the URL.

Instead of the url query at the end to select your root folder and path (the section after the `?` in the url given) try and create a URL in the form following:

`http://mySiteCollection.com/sites/SiteInQuestion/My Library/Folder1/Second Folder`

You may need to have `/SiteInQuestion/Lists/My Library` or similar. But you should be able to add the url in a more "File Explorer" like way.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Yep, it works. Thanks!